# Selenium and Python on Snow Leopard

Tags: python, macos, selenium

I'm trying to use the stock Python (2.6.1) on Snow Leopard with Selenium. Being quite new to Python, I'm a at a bit of a loss for what I've done wrong, as this exact same process worked just fine on my ubuntu box:

1. sudo easy_install -U selenium
2. Create a simple test with Firefox Selenium UI, and export it as Python WebDriver (as mytest.py)
3. $ python mytest.py (which results in:

This error message:

```
E

======================================================================
ERROR: test_mytest_py (__main__.MytestPy)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mytest.py", line 8, in setUp
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 46, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 41, in launch_browser
    self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 66, in _start_from_profile_path
    Popen([self._start_cmd, "-silent"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1106, in _execute_child
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.302s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

One thing worth noting is that when I ran "sudo easy_install -U selenium", I did get a warning:

```
$ sudo easy_install -U selenium
Searching for selenium
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/selenium/
Reading http://www.openqa.org/
Reading http://code.google.com/p/selenium/
Reading http://seleniumhq.org/
Best match: selenium 2.14.0
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/selenium/selenium-2.14.0.tar.gz#md5=8de9ee26d699d699f846f14f9a184e60
Processing selenium-2.14.0.tar.gz
Running selenium-2.14.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-yQVlpa/selenium-2.14.0/egg-dist-tmp-svoAjf
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'src_root'
warning: no files found matching 'docs/api/py/index.rst'
Adding selenium 2.14.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium-2.14.0-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for selenium
Finished processing dependencies for selenium
```

Comment: do you have XCode installed? If not that should fix it

Comment: @pna, I do have XCode installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your Firefox binary location first. Does it placed at here: /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
?

For more information, please check this page: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver

Comment: YES! I always place apps I download into Applications/-MyApps/ ... After moving Firefox into the Applications root dir, everything works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: I had moved Firefox into a subdirectory in /Applications, once I moved it back the error is fixed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Selenium but the traceback indicates that it doesn't have a usable path to Firefox.

You will need to change its configuration/profile file to give it a path to an executable version of Firefox.

The profile as it stands probably has the default location of Firefox on a linux box (hence why it works on Ubuntu).  But it wont be at this location on OSX.

Comment: That may be, but where would I configure this?